# ListView in DrawerLayout with onFling gesture for list rows

Tags: android, gestures, drawerlayout

I have a `DrawerLayout` that open from the right side of the screen.
In the sliding layout of the drawer, I have a `ListView` and I would like to implement the `onFling` gesture on the list rows, in order to get the swipe gesture from right to left (so that is not an ambiguous gesture).

The problem is that the drawer catches the swipe gesture and consumes it. So the list won't get the gesture. How can I tell the drawer to not consume that gesture if it is open?

The code is like every gesture implementation with the `GestureDetector`

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new LeftToRightSwipeGesture());

mList.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
  {
    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
});
```

and the gesture listener

```
private class LeftToRightSwipeGesture extends SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent end, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
      if (Math.abs(end.getY() - start.getY()) < FLING_MAX_OFF_PATH && Math.abs(velocityX) > FLING_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY && Math.abs(start.getX() - end.getX()) > FLING_MIN_DISTANCE
          && end.getX() > start.getX())
      {
        //DO STUFF
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
```